# Linux Bash: while loop can't loop through file (where lines are divided by \r\n)

Tags: bash

I have this loop:

```
while read p; do echo $p; done < ~/Documents/tempfile
```

Which has to loop through each line of `~/Documents/tempfile`.

When lines in that file are separated by `\r\n` - loop can echo only first line.

When I manually edit the file (hit `Enter` in the end of each line) - loop can echo all lines.

Does Bash use something else instead of `\r\n`?

**Found a problem:**

I had to add `\r\n` in the end of file as well.

After that it started returning all lines.

Thank you all.

Comment: It's echoing each line; however, with `\r` being the last character of each line, the cursor moves to the beginning of each line and the following line overwrites it.

Comment: To answer the actual question, `bash` assumes UNIX newlines (which consist of a linefeed alone).

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem with: `echo -e "a\r\nb\r\nc\r" | while read p; do echo $p; done`  Could you try the same test?

Comment: @putnamhill - ha.. this code works fine

Comment: I'm getting it from the site, using cURL. is it possible that cURL has some weird way to encode `\n` ? Or maybe its some sort of encoding problem? (say `\n` in UTF vs Unicode)

Comment: @Serge I would be surprised if cURL is altering the data. Do you have access to the site? If so try adding the \r\n delimited abc file to the server and repeat the test with cURL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of `IFS` variable I believe:

```
(IFS=$'\r\n' && while read p; do echo $p; done < ~/Documents/tempfile)
```

Comment: Why the parens? Couldn't you just write it `while IFS=$'\r\n' read p…`?

Comment: @kojiro I believe that's to keep from having to do `OLDIFS="$IFS";IFS='\r\n';` ... `IFS="$OLDIFS"`

Comment: @kojiro: Parentheses are being used to make sure this command is executed in a sub shell to avoid messing up `IFS` in current shell.

Comment: Well, the *while read loop* will create an implicit subshell, but the explicit subshell isn't necessary. If you do an assignment immediately before a command that assignment is only exported to the command – it doesn't stick around in the parent environment. It says so under `SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION` in the bash manpage. You can also test it with `DOGS=123 read foo <<< 'hi'; echo $DOGS` --> no output.

Comment: @kojiro: Good point mate. In that case I guess it wasn't necessary.

Comment: On my site I join many strings with `\r\n`, then download them to a file using cURL, and then do this processing. My main goal is to process each substring.

Comment: @SergeVinogradoff: Can you dump output of `cat -vte ~/Documents/tempfile`

Comment: Nah if that's the only way - I'll just stick with temp file. Still can't echo all lines though.

Comment: No no I am not giving cat as solution :P I was trying to see output of `cat -vte ~/Documents/tempfile` to understand your input file format.

Answer (score 2):

Linux and *nix are using `\n` as a newline sequence; Windows for example uses `\r\n`.

You can use `dos2unix` or `tr` to convert it:

```
dos2unix -b yourfile
```

(-b creates a backup of the original file)

or

```
tr -d '\r' < input.file > output.file
```

or (to meet your requirements, thanks to kojiro for mentioning!):

```
 tr -d '\r' < input.file | while read p; do echo $p; done < ~/Documents/tempfile
```

Comment: or `tr -d '\r' < input.file | while read…` to meed OP's needs without modifying the original file.

Comment: I tried to generate a file with `\n` line endings instead of `\r\n`. Kate says it's UNIX endings now. (before it said "DOS endings"). However looping through lines still not working. Maybe it's not a result of `\r\n`?

Answer (score 2):

`-d` is used to terminate the input line with [read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html). See if the following works

```
while read -d $'\r\n' p; do echo $p; done < ~/Documents/tempfile
```

Comment: @anubhava, alright, but note that `-d` is the line terminator with `read`, not `IFS`. `IFS` is used for intraline splitting.

Comment: Just tried it. Same thing - returns first line. Is it possible that it locks output buffer or something?

Comment: @SergeVinogradoff, how many lines does the file have. Replace the `read` loop with two separate `read` invocations and check the return code for the second `read` invocation